# What algorithm should I use?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, supervised-learning

I am having trouble figuring out what model fits my dataset and problem. Early thoughts are either Hidden Markov or Dynamic Baysien Network. The order matters from day 1 - 5. The data set is a 4x5 matrix with the first column being the day.

The training data set is time series data with 3  variables. The variables being Sleep Hours, Body Temperature and Water Consumption. Over the course of the 5 days the subjects variables either increase or decrease for each row. On day 6 the subject says that he does not feel well (migraine, stuffed nose, sick). This makes this set the supervised training set because we now know the outcome = subject becomes sick due to the past 5 days.

If I want to test it against future datasets from the same subject what model/algorithm would I use to generate the probability of the subject getting sick or not.

The order matters as with each day there is a decrease or increase.

Please let me know your opinions.